# C# Unity3D Error: List<int>.ToArray() problem

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, integer, integer-overflow

I'm building a complex mesh via C# scripting in Unity3D. Following my generation codes, I pass my triangle data to `UnityEngine.Mesh.triangles`. My triangle data is stored in a variable typed as `List<int>`. And the type of `UnityEngine.Mesh.triangles` is `int[]`. So I used `List<int>.ToArray()` method to convert it. But after conversion, some items in the `UnityEngine.Mesh.triangles`(`int[]`) are not identical to my triangle data(`List<int>`). To be more specific, I found that `List<int>` typed variables could store numbers greater than 65535, but int[] can not do that.

codes:

```
List<int> ts = new List<int>();
//generation codes
mesh.triangles = ts.ToArray();
```

And I use this code to test it in Unity:

```
for (int i = 0; i < mesh.triangles.Length; i++)
            if (mesh.triangles[i] != ts[i]) Debug.Log(mesh.triangles[i].ToString() + " ≠ " + ts[i].ToString());
```

then I get logs such as 0≠65536, indicating that there is a overflow.

Comment: How much greater then 65535? int[] nums = new int[] {655359999 } is ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but `int[]` can not do that.

Of course it can it is an array of `int` so it supports the entire range of `int`.

The issue is most probably not with `int[]` but probably rather with the Unity mesh API.

By default a `Mesh` in Unity can maximum have `65535` vertices. Therefore also the `triangles` will not store any value above that.

If you want to have more vertices than that you need to change the [`Mesh.indexFormat`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh-indexFormat.html) to [`IndexFormat.UInt32`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rendering.IndexFormat.UInt32.html)